# Circle not draw in Google Maps with OpenLayers

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, openlayers-3, ol3-google-maps

I am trying to draw a circle in OpenLayers using Google Maps (olGM). 
I don´t know why it not draw a circle, because in OSM working perfectly.

```
var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([latd, lond], 'EPSG:4326', 
'EPSG:3857'), 1000);
var center = circle.getCenter();
var CircleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
```

Edit again. Finally I could to draw the Circle. But, my question is, how can I access to Radius and Center from Circle1? And modifying Circle1, I modify Circle in the same time.

I am using:

```
var circle1 = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([latd, lond], 
'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), radius);
var circle = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circle1, 232, 0);
var CircleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circle geometries are currently not supported in ol3-google-maps, see: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/blob/master/LIMITATIONS.md#circle-geometry

If you wish to contribute it, you can create a pull request on the library's GitHub.

Comment: I would like to do it. So, there are another alternative for draw a Circle and control the radius and center in Ol3-google-maps?

Comment: You could create a regular polygon out of it using `ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle`, see: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.5.0/src/ol/geom/polygon.js#L418-L442

Comment: Ok, thanks. It resolve this. However the function .getCenter is not available there. But, I don´t have another option.